# Project Euler Problem 2 in Python with Error Message

Tags: python

I am a complete beginner in coding and was trying problems from Project Euler in Python. Could anyone please explain what is wrong with my code?
Problem: Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:

1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...

By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

```
a = []
x = 1
y = 2

for y in range (1, 400000):
  if x % 2:
    a.append(x)
  x = y, y = x + y


print(sum(a))
```

I received the error message "cannot unpack non-iterable int object". What does this message mean and how to avoid it?

Answer (score 2):

You get that error because you have the line `x = y, y = x + y` which is interpreted as an attempt to unpack values from an iterable into y, y, so you need to have a new line between `x = y` and `y = x + y`.

However since x is assigned with the value of y before y is updated, the better option is to change the line to `x, y = y, x + y`as JackTheCrab suggested in a comment.

Look the below example as well to explain the error:

```py
price, amount = ["10$", 15] #iterable that can be unpacked
price, amount = 15 # this is just an int and this row will throw error "Cannot unpack non-iterable int object"
```

Comment: His code still won't actually put out Fibonacci series though

Comment: Yes that is very true, but the error in question is explained. The solving of the Euler problem i will leave to Matthew to figure out ;)

Comment: Just to add for Matthew, you can also do `x,y = y, x+y` if you want to have it in one line

Answer (score 1):

> `x = y, y = x + y`

When i take away the addition from the end and the assignment from the beginning, the error still is there.

```py
y, y = x
```

Output : an error. about non-iterable int ! Because you **can** unpack an iterable.

```
iterable = [0, 1, 2]
zero = iterable[0]
one = iterable[1]
two = iterable[2]
```

is not very good (sorry for my bad english ...) to use, because you have to type `iterable[n]` again and again. That's why you can unpack such iterables like this:

```
iterable = [0, 1, 2]
zero, one, two = iterable
```

This will produce the same result as the above long version.

Back to your code,

```
x = y, y = x + y
```

the python interpreter will first work on the assignment (`x = ...`). To resolve it, it tries to unpack `x + y` into two values, but this is not possible of course.

To declare two variables on one line, you have to separate the assignments with a colon `;`, not a comma. But when you do just that, x will have the same value as y at the beginning, and so y will then be the double of itself, which surely is not what you wanted. Maybe you should do it like this ?

```py
a = []
x = 1
y = 2

for y in range (1, 400000):
  if x % 2:
    a.append(x)
  x, y = y, x + y
  # above is equivalent to
  # temp = y
  # y = x + y
  # x = temp
print(sum(a))
```

Comment: @MatthewTan please accept and optionally upvote the answer that helped you the most !